# One of my user accounts logs in without desktop environment

Tags: unity, login

When I log in to my main user account on Ubuntu 11.10 ,the desktop environment (unity bar, clock, volume control, etc.) is not there. All I have is the desktop background with a menu bar across the top which appears to be for nautilus (options like File->New folder).

My other accounts log in like normal.

I have recently followed [these instructions](http://mac.linux.be/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=95) to give my main user account access to an OSX partition, but I think I have logged in successfully since then.
I am able to get a terminal by pressing ctrl+alt+t, but when I typed `unity` the whole thing crashed.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? I have a separate administrator account I can use if needed.

Comment: I know this gets thrown about alot but have you tried 'unity --reset' in the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an issue of broken configuration files

I suggest you create a new account and move all the documents and stuff to the new account, as it might be hard to get a fix for your problem